# Mock IDisposable.Dispose() method in C# Moq

Tags: c#, moq

Below class is given to me for which I need to write test case. All other test case I was able to write except for **Dispose()**

**Note:** I am not allowed to modify the class DataProvider.

Please can someone help me in writing test case for Dispose() method using Moq framework.

```
public class DataProvider<TInput, TRequest, TResponse, TOutput>:IDataProvider<TInput,TOutput> , IDisposable where TRequest : class, new()
where TResponse : class, new()
{

    private readonly ICompose<TInput, TRequest> requestComp;
    private readonly ICompose<TResponse, TOutput> responseComp;
    private bool disposed;
    private readonly IData idata;

    public DataProvider(IConverter<TInput, TRequest> requestComp,
                           IConverter<TResponse, TOutput> responseComp,
                           IDealer dealer,
                           string passcode)
    {
        this.requestComp = requestComp;
        this.responseComp = responseComp;
        this.idata= dealer.GetCalculatedData(passcode);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.disposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.idata?.Dispose();

        this.disposed = true;
    }

    #endregion - IDispose end


    public void GetData(TInput input)
    {
        //Do something here 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code crucially lacks the declaration of `client` and where it's coming from. If it's internal to the class and owned by the instance (the common case), there quite literally is nothing to test as the effects of `Dispose` are invisible (unless `disposed` is checked in other methods to throw an `ObjectDisposedException`, that could be tested). If it is somehow related to any of the parameters passed in externally, it might be a different story.

Comment: @JeroenMostert : I have modified the code, please check now.

Comment: In the code as written, `DataProvider.Dispose` has an observable effect, which is calling `Dispose` on the object returned by `dealer.GetCalculatedData()`. So you could mock `IDealer.GetCalculatedData` to return an `IData` mock whose `Dispose` registers that it has been called, and then your test is verifying this -- but this test does seem very closely coupled to the current behavior of the class, and this might be inappropriately pinning down what should be considered an implementation detail.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I am not expert into Moq. Please spare some code snippets to elaborate on what you said above?

Comment: It's been a hot minute since I've used Moq. Something like `var data = new Mock<IData>(); var dealer = new Mock<IDealer>(); dealer.Setup(d => d.GetCalculatedData(It.IsAny<string>()).Returns(data.Object); var dataProvider = new DataProvider(..., dealer.Object, ...); dataProvider.Dispose(); data.Verify(d => d.Dispose())`. Fix and tweak as necessary.

Comment: No need to be an expert. Check the docs here to get a better understanding of how to use moq https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that should explain each step of the test.

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    // Arrange.
    var mockData = new Mock<IData>();
    var mockDealer = new Mock<IDealer>();

    // Setup mockDealer so that the GetCalculatedData returns the object from mockData.
    mockDealer.Setup(d => d.GetCalculatedData(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(mockData.Object);
    
    // Create the tested object (the DataProvider) using mocked dependencies.
    var dataProvider = new DataProvider<object, object, object, object>(
        requestComp: It.IsAny<IConverter<object, object>>(), 
        responseComp: It.IsAny<IConverter<object, object>>(), 
        dealer: mockDealer.Object,
        passcode: It.IsAny<string>()
    ); 
    
    // Act.
    dataProvider.Dispose();

    // Assert.
    // Verify that Dispose was called on the IData object.
    mockData.Verify(d => d.Dispose());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Batesian, @JeroenMostert, @Nkosi: Thanks for your answers.

I tweaked the code as per my requirement and it worked.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
// Arrange.
var mockData = new Mock<IData>();
var mockDealer = new Mock<IDealer>();
var reqComposeMock = new Mock<IConverter<object, object>>();
var resComposeMock = new Mock<IConverter<object, object>>();

// Setup mockDealer so that the GetCalculatedData returns the object from mockData.
mockDealer.Setup(d => d.GetCalculatedData(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(mockData.Object);

// Create the tested object (the DataProvider) using mocked dependencies.
var dataProvider = new DataProvider<object, object, object, object>(
    requestComp: reqComposeMock.Object, 
    responseComp: resComposeMock.Object, 
    dealer: mockDealer.Object,
    passcode: "passcode"
); 

// Act.
dataProvider.Dispose();

// Assert.
// Verify that Dispose was called on the IData object.
mockData.Verify(d => d.Dispose());
}
```